# ZoomH4n - Some kind of an answer

Tags: field-recording, zoom-h4n, noise, equipment, microphone

After recording again and being puzzled again by the levels on my Zoom H4n, I googled a bit and found this awesome handheld recorder shootout:

["Noise floor of the on-board mics and mic-inputs - Zoom H4, Zoom H4n, Edirol R-4, Sony PCM-D50"
by Martin Doppelbauer](https://web.archive.org/web/20170526143147/http://www.martin-doppelbauer.de:80/fieldrecorder/)

I thought this might be of interest to you guys....

Anyway, I'm a bit pissed because I have this great ambience in the part of the basement where all the plumbing passes of the building I live in...Dripping and gurgling etc..
Wanting to get a stereo recording, I whipped out my Zoom, cranked up the levels to 100 and recorded 7 minutes....while monitoring on headphones at 45 (on the headphone output meters)

I'm looking at the waveform in Audiofinder and it looks terrible...i.e. flat:

[alt text http://db.tt/81PgtYce](http://db.tt/81PgtYce)

For those of you that new all about this...sorry to bore you. The comparison linked above should still be fairly interesting anyway. I mean, I've used the H4n for lot's of things and have been satisfied with the performance, noise-floor aside.

Anyway, I guess I'm buying one of these

[image]
<sub>(source: [sounddevices.com](http://www.sounddevices.com/download/photos/552-front-1800px.jpg))</sub>

and one of these then

[image]
<sub>(source: [sanken-mic.com](http://www.sanken-mic.com/upload/prd/img/1001600.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Lucky you, have fun with the new gear.

Comment: Unfortunately it'll take a bit of saving....but for advertising and corporate shoots the 552 will be a winner.